# Split() an expression with a break line in Java

Tags: java, string, split

Which method of `java.lang.String` should I use to split the string below into an array or collection of strings, the splitting being done with respect to the character of the line break?

`String str="This is a string\nthis is the next line.\nHello World.";`
I think that method is `split()`.

`String[] arrOfStr = str.split("\n", limit)`;

but I don't know what to put in the `limit` in order to follow the requirements.

I did that code:

```java
public class Split {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str="This is a string\nthis is the next line.\nHello World.";
        String[] arrOfStr = str.split("\n");
        System.out.println(arrOfStr);

    }

}
```

But the result is [Ljava.lang.String;@36baf30c
I don't understand.

Comment: Its not necessary - there is a [one argument form](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) and a [two argument form](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-).

Comment: Also, this question should be tagged with [tag:java]. In future, please tag all questions with the language being used.

Comment: And regarding the output from printing the array, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to pass a `limit` to [`String#split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) if you want to split for all occurrences of `\n`. To show the contents of the array (instead of the reference), you can use [`Arrays.toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString-java.lang.Object:A-).

```
String str = "This is a string\nthis is the next line.\nHello World.";

String[] arrOfStr = str.split("\n");

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrOfStr));
```

*Output:*

```
[This is a string, this is the next line., Hello World.]
```

---

To see what the `limit` argument does, you can write a *for*-loop and observe the result like this:

```
String str = "This is a string\nthis is the next line.\nHello World.";
for (int limit = 0; limit < 4; limit++) {
    String[] arrWithLimit = str.split("\n", limit);
    System.out.println(limit + ": " + Arrays.toString(arrWithLimit));
}
```

*Output:*

```
0: [This is a string, this is the next line., Hello World.]
1: [This is a string
this is the next line.
Hello World.]
2: [This is a string, this is the next line.
Hello World.]
3: [This is a string, this is the next line., Hello World.]
```

You can see that the parameter limits the amount of splits being applied. `0` considers all occurrences (same as without `limit`). With `1` there is only 1 element in `arrWithLimit` and with `2` there are 2 elements.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through the array that you created from the split method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str="This is a string\nthis is the next line.\nHello World.";
    String[] arrOfStr = str.split("\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < arrOfStr.length; i++){
        System.out.println(arrOfStr[i]);
    }
}
```

Also another way to look at the contents is to use Arrays.deepToString() such as:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arrOfStr));
```

This results in the following outputs:

for loop iterating output:

```
This is a string
this is the next line.
Hello World.
```

deepToString output:

```
[This is a string, this is the next line., Hello World.]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String str="This is a string\nthis is the next line.\nHello World.";
String ab[]=    str.split("[\\r\\n]+");
Arrays.stream(ab).forEach(abc -> System.out.println(abc + " "));
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace in your code:

```
System.out.println(arrOfStr); // it is printing the memory location since the `toString` 
                              //   method is implemented in this way
```

by:

```
 for(int i = 0; i<arrOfStr.length; i++)
     System.out.println(arrOfStr[i]);
   }
```